# Specify specific columns in ec2-describe-instance-status command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, ec2-api-tools

`ec2-describe-instance-status` always returns all columns specified in [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeInstanceStatus.html)

I need a way to know just the `state name` and `state code` of the instance of instance.

Is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 2):

These days, it's best to use the `[aws-cli][1]`:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,State.Name,State.Code]' --output text
i-38b3ef47  stopped 80
i-28afe386  stopped 80
i-9da318a2  stopped 80
i-3c5ac651  stopped 80
i-4f45ec91  running 16
i-6d231640  stopped 80
```

Answer (score 1):

`ec2-describe-instance-status | grep '^INSTANCE\s' | cut -f2,4,5`

Comment: I will clarify more. In SQL select you can specify columns. In above command, we are taking all data and using Grep we are merely filtering from complete result.

Comment: True. But reading the documentation it doesn't seem like doing what you want is possible, so what I suggest above is a workaround.